# python pandas - Add a new column by merging 2 columns based on a condition

Tags: pandas, merge

Here is the data frame I am working with:
df = igan[["SUBJID", "LBSPCCND", "LBSPCCND_OTHER"]]
df.head(12)
[image]

I need to merge LBSPCCND and LBSPCCND_OTHER into a new column called LBSPCCND_ALL.  I want to keep all values in LBSPCCND except where it is = "Other".  I want to take all values from LBSPCCND_OTHER where it is not blank and merge those values into the new column.  (all blanks should mean that LBSPCCND has a valid value.)  I can't have "Other" in my data set.  SUBJID is what I am using as a unique identifier to merge this data back into my main data frame that you don't see here.

I put together these conditions, but I'm unsure how to get the new column based on these conditions.

```
condition1 = df["LBSPCCND"] != "Other"
condition2 = df["LBSPCCND_OTHER"] != ""
df["LBSPCCND_ALL"] = df[df[condition1 & condition2]]
```

#This is not working  I get:  Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (13, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way :

```
df["LBSPCCND_ALL"] = df["LBSPCCND_OTHER"].replace("", None).fillna(df["LBSPCCND"])
```

Another variant,

```
df["LBSPCCND_ALL"] = df["LBSPCCND"].replace("Other", None).fillna(df["LBSPCCND_OTHER"])
```

Output :

```
print(df["LBSPCCND_ALL"])

 0                             Adequate specimen
1                              Adequate specimen
2                              Adequate specimen
3                                 Limited Sample
4     Paraffin block; paraffin-embedded specimen
5                              Adequate specimen
6                              Adequate specimen
7                              Adequate specimen
8                               Pathology Report
9                              Adequate specimen
10                             Adequate specimen
11                                  Unacceptable
Name: LBSPCCND_ALL, dtype: object
```

Comment: The 1st option didn't work for me, but the other variant did. thank you so much.  I'm trying to figure out how to accept the answer.  Thank you again!